# How to send signals to all processes of my program

Tags: linux, c++

I have a program which has a daemon and some other commandline stuff, which all may run simultaneously. I have a condition where I need to kill all of them, but I don't want to parse /proc since that will be so much for think. I'm thinking about setting their Process Group IDs to something I know, but I think it won't work since they should not be in the same session. Is there a way to do this ?

Please don't mind if it sounds dumb to you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that 'some other commandline stuff' started by the daemon, or by the user?

Comment: By the user, the daemon received input from them and acts as requested.

Comment: Isn't that what `killall` does?

Comment: What is the reason for killing the commandline client programs? Good design would be to make them exit automatically as soon as connection to the daemon is lost.